# Loading symbols for remote debugging

Tags: symbols, remote-debugging, debug-symbols, tfs-sdk

I am trying to debug a plug-in for TFS 2010 using the code [found here](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/10/27/devleoping-and-debugging-server-side-event-handlers-in-tfs-2010.aspx).  That example recommends using TFS installed locally to debug.  I wanted to try it with a dev TFS 2010 Server I have setup.  So I installed Remote Debugger x64 on that machine and tried to remote debug.

There are 3 **w3wp.exe** processes running on that machine.  But I tried attaching to each of them and every time I do my break point say:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

When I build I output all the files from the build to the plug-in folder on the TFS Machine.  Should I be keeping some file local for symbol loading?  Is there someway to manually point to the symbol file?  What is the symbol file?

**Update:** I got it to work for a few runs.  But now it is not working again.  (TFS is up and working, but the break points give me the above message....)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out.

1. Go to Debugging->Options and Settings.
2. Select the Symbols option on the left.
3. Add a new symbols file location (to the location you are deploying to)
4. Select load all symbols.

RESULT: The disabled break points are now enabled